# How can I index nearby devices into a UITableView and pair with the selected devices?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, bluetooth

How can I find nearby iPhones and iPods running the same application and index them into a UITableView?  Then how would I go about pairing with the selected devices over bluetooth to carry out an undisclosed process?

Answer (score 0):

GKSession is the easiest I've seen, although it took me about 4-5 hrs to do and that was not messing around just straight typing you will need a client model 
A server model hostTableView and a joingameTableView and not to mention quite a few delegates to transfer the info back and forth between the server model and client model and back and forth between the host and the client(joingameTableView) they all talk back and forth to make that happen. You can use bonjour and other methods but I haven't used any other. I will try to post an example that compiles to git sometime soon, there is just way to much logic involved for me to explain in a post! Hope I helped at least guided you in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm... I'll definitely look into this, thanks.  Doesn't look too simple to me, but can't be overly complicated right?